# Loading fragments in a RelativeLayout

Tags: android, android-layout

I have two RelativeLayouts inside a FrameLayout.  The idea is that they will occupy the left and right edges of the screen with the first View (a Text View in this case) occupying the middle portion of the screen.

Within each RelativeLayout there will be a vertical list of composite buttons.  Each button has a fragment next to it that slides open when clicked.  So clicking a button on the left-hand side of the screen causes a list of options to slide open to the right of the button.  Clicking a button on the right side of the screen should cause a list of options to slide open to the LEFT of the button.

The RelativeLayout on the left side of the screen works perfectly.  Cicking a button causes the fragment to appear to the right of the button.  But I can't get the RelativeLayout on the right side of the screen to behave correctly.  When you click one of the buttons, all the buttons below it slide to the left.  I can't seem to anchor the buttons to the right edge so the fragments always appear to the left of the buttons with any remaining buttons along the right edge of the screen.

What am I doing wrong?  Is there a better way to do this?

The fragments are attached to the buttons in Activity onCreate().

This is what it looks like when no buttons have been clicked
[image]

Clicking a button on the left side loads the fragment correctly.  Everything stays anchored to the left edge.
[image]

Clicking a button on the right side is the problem.  The buttons do not stay anchored to the right edge and instead float to the left.  GGG behaves differently because (I think) the fragment has not yet been attached to the onClick listener. 
[image]

```
   <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:text="@string/hello_world"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal" 
        android:background="#000000"/>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#33ffffff">

        <com.example.fragmentbuttonstest.widget.SelectionButton
            android:id="@+id/sb_aaa_selection"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/sb_aaa_frag_container"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/sb_aaa_selection"/>

        <com.example.fragmentbuttonstest.widget.SelectionButton
            android:id="@+id/sb_bbb_selection"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/sb_aaa_selection" />
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/sb_bbb_frag_container"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/sb_bbb_selection"
            android:layout_below="@+id/sb_aaa_selection" />

        <com.example.fragmentbuttonstest.widget.SelectionButton
            android:id="@+id/sb_ccc_selection"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/sb_bbb_selection" />
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/sb_ccc_frag_container"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/sb_ccc_selection"
            android:layout_below="@+id/sb_bbb_selection"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

 <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#33ffffff"
        android:layout_gravity="top|right">

       <com.example.fragmentbuttonstest.widget.SelectionButton
            android:id="@+id/sb_ddd_selection"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/sb_ddd_frag_container" /> 
      <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/sb_ddd_frag_container"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>


      <com.example.fragmentbuttonstest.widget.SelectionButton
            android:id="@+id/sb_eee_selection"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/sb_ddd_selection"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/sb_eee_frag_container"           />
       <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/sb_eee_frag_container"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/sb_ddd_selection" />


      <com.example.fragmentbuttonstest.widget.SelectionButton
            android:id="@+id/sb_fff_selection"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/sb_eee_selection"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/sb_ddd_frag_container" />
      <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/sb_fff_frag_container"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/sb_eee_selection" />

    </RelativeLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: please post your expected design of xml and current view

Comment: "I have two RelativeLayouts inside a FrameLayout." - framelayout can hold only one item.

Comment: @GoranHoriaMihail I think that's a good rule in most cases but not a requirement. ...if I'm reading the API guide correctly.  In this situation, I want the first View to occupy the entire screen with the content of the RelativeLayouts being overlays that sit above it on each edge of the screen.  I'm not aware of any other way to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't look like I'm going to get a response so I'll share the solution I came up with...

I'm not happy at all about having to position each element manually but (so far) I haven't been able to get everything to align correctly by wrapping the buttons and fragments in layouts.

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:text="@string/hello_world"
        android:textAlignment="center" />

    <!-- Left side button bar -->

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#33ffffff" />

    <!-- AAA Selection -->

    <com.example.fragmentbuttonstest.widget.SelectionButton
        android:id="@+id/sb_aaa_selection"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/sb_aaa_frag_container"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="45dp" />

    <!-- BBB Selection -->

    <com.example.fragmentbuttonstest.widget.SelectionButton
        android:id="@+id/sb_bbb_selection"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="45dp" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/sb_bbb_frag_container"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="45dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="45dp" />

    <!-- CCC Selection -->

    <com.example.fragmentbuttonstest.widget.SelectionButton
        android:id="@+id/sb_ccc_selection"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="90dp" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/sb_ccc_frag_container"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="45dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="90dp" />

    <!-- DDD Selection -->

    <com.example.fragmentbuttonstest.widget.SelectionButton
        android:id="@+id/sb_ddd_selection"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="135dp" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/sb_ddd_frag_container"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="45dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="135dp" />

    <!-- EEE Position Selection -->

    <com.example.fragmentbuttonstest.widget.SelectionButton
        android:id="@+id/sb_eee_selection"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="180dp" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/sb_eee_frag_container"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="45dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="180dp" />



    <!-- Right Side Button Bar -->
    <!-- Right Side Background -->

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="45dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="top|right"
        android:background="#33ffffff" />

    <!-- FFF Selection -->

    <com.example.fragmentbuttonstest.widget.SelectionButton
        android:id="@+id/sb_fff_selection"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="top|right" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/sb_fff_frag_container"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_marginRight="45dp" />

    <!-- GGG Selection -->

    <com.example.fragmentbuttonstest.widget.SelectionButton
        android:id="@+id/sb_ggg_selection"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_marginTop="45dp" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/sb_ggg_frag_container"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_marginRight="45dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="45dp" />

    <!-- HHH Selection -->

    <com.example.fragmentbuttonstest.widget.SelectionButton
        android:id="@+id/sb_hhh_selection"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_marginTop="90dp" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/sb_hhh_frag_container"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_marginRight="45dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="45dp" />

    <!-- III Selection -->

    <com.example.fragmentbuttonstest.widget.SelectionButton
        android:id="@+id/sb_iii_selection"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_marginTop="135dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/sb_player_frag_container" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/sb_iii_frag_container"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_marginRight="45dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="90dp" />

    <!-- JJJ Selection -->

    <com.example.fragmentbuttonstest.widget.SelectionButton
        android:id="@+id/sb_jjj_selection"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_marginTop="180dp" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/sb_jjj_frag_container"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_marginRight="45dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="135dp" />

</FrameLayout>
```